# Oracle/Excel ODBC username/password error

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

We have recently created a new database instance for an upgraded application.  When we try to connect to the DB using ODBC from Excel it returns a "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied" error.

I am able to successfully logon to the database with SQL+ from the command line using the same username and password.

If I switch back to the previous database I can connect successfully using Excel.

Does anyone know what if anything needs setup on the new DB to allow it to accept the ODBC connection.

Something springs to mind years back when we first set this up about either username/passwords being converted to uppercase when trying to connect so both the USERNAME and PASSWORD are set to uppercase.  I'm not sure whether anything else is needed server side or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is coming from more of an MS SQL point of view but I've seen people create a new database and not open up the SQL logins for anything by local access. Adjusting permissions to allow SQL credentials to be used was sufficient to open up the pipe (assuming the named pipe/TCP/IP connection is similarly allowed).

Comment: What are the old/new database versions?  Values are case-sensitive.

Comment: Old: Oracle 11.2.0.1.0
New: Oracle 11.2.0.4.3

Comment: It's got to be ODBC doing this.  Oracle is on 10.something, and the download is free.  Can you install the latest and see if that fixes it?

Comment: But if it works against a 11.2.0.1.0 instance, why would the client not work against the 11.2.0.4.3 release?

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01017: invalid username/password is always because of wrong username password combination.

Quite likely that the password is not in the right case in your Excel.
For the case sensitivity, check the SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON parameter in the DB.
If parameter is set to true, passwords are case sensitive.

Comment: We added "SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON" earlier today to check if that was the issue.  It still didn't work after adding it.

Comment: What was SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON set to before, and what is it set to now?

Comment: It was set to false.  We also checked the old DB and that was the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't to do anything with the database, it is the connection string I'm using to connect to the database. It's using the old instance instead of the new one!!! I need to look at why that is using the old one when tnsnames is setup to point to the new one.